# Including &amp; in my combobox

Tags: java, xml, gwt, uibinder

I added a few items to my ComboBox using gwt UIBinder.

```
<g:item>--select one--</g:item>
<g:item>Dispute Referral Form</g:item>
<g:item>Dispute Settlement Clause</g:item>
<g:item>Procedures &amp; Rules</g:item>
<g:item>Standard Terms &amp; Conditions</g:item>
<g:item>Taxation Rules</g:item>
```

however if I refresh the browser(google chrome) Procedures `&amp;` Rules is displayed in the combobox as apposed to just Procedures **&** Rules

How can I get the the browser only to display '&' as opposed to`&amp;`

Comment: It looks like it escaping HTML for you already, have you tried just using `&`?

Comment: FYI, this has been fixed in GWT http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/detail?r=10891 and will be in GWT 2.5 (to be released in a month or so). In the mean time, I believe there's no solution but to add it in Java rather than UiBinder.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution - but a work around.

Define in java const array of Strings and add them in to list box in the constructor right after the `initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));`
and wait for GWT 2.5 as mentioned by  [Thomas Broyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116472/thomas-broyer)

By the way this will allow you to define Ids and values separately. For what it worth :-)